# acces to previous element in element of arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

i explain my question with an example :

```
    myArray=[10,15,42,74,65,2,7,9]
```

so, how can i acces to All elements for example before element '65' :

```
    newArray=[10,15,42,74]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+copy+array+until+value+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) : `const newArray = myArray.slice(0,myArray.indexOf(65))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.slice(start, length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get just part of your original array, and [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get index of the number 65.

```js
let array = [10, 15, 42, 74, 65, 2, 7, 9]

// 0, because you want to start on the first index (10)
let newArray = array.slice(0, array.indexOf(65))
```

Comment: thank you and how can access next to 65 ?

Comment: You mean after 65?

Comment: yes thats true.

Comment: The two arguments are start, and lenght of the new array. If the second argument is missing, you can the new array will be as long as possible. All you need to do is remove the 0 argument